# What is the best and fastest way to append to list in json file?

Tags: python, json, list

So, I have a `.json` file it is a `list` of dictionaries. Currently, I just update the file by just have a list of dictionaries in a variable, append that list and write over the existing `.json` file. However, in the future, the size of the list can be extremely large that it might take very long time to write the file or even larger than a variable can hold. So, I would like to just be able to append to my list in `.json`, preferable, on the top.

Currently, here is my code:

```
import json

new = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}]
now = [{'d': '4'}, {'e': '5'}, {'f': '6'}]

for i in range(len(new)):
     now.insert(i, new[i])

##now = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}, {'e': '5'}, {'f': '6'}]

with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(now, f)
```

I would like to do this, but without having to store list in `now` because it could get too big, and without rewrite the whole file every single times because it could take too much time.

Comment: There is no (portable) way to modify a file in the middle without rewriting the rest of it. A common solution is to use a database instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add to the list without reading the file in a simple way.

If you have the guarantee that the file always contains valid JSON. Then maybe you can run the `sed` command to add items in the correct location assuming that you have access to sed cmd.

```
import subprocess
import json

new = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}, {'c': '3'}]

# myfile.json contents => [{"d": "4"}, {"e": "5"}, {"f": "6"}]

try:
    subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', '-e', 's/\[/\[{}, /'.format(json.dumps(new)[1:-1]), 'myfile.json'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will add entries to the beginning of the list. Modify the sed command as your need. Also, this will only work if the file already contains a non-empty JSON list. But those situations can be handled with a bit of logic.